EF Core Change Tracking, without DbContext
I'm using Blazor Server Side and EF Core for a project. The issue I have: change tracking is redundant as it is suggested to create short lived contexts using DB factory.
E.g.
public class OrderService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> _contextFactory;

    public OrderService(IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public Order GetById(int id)
    {
        using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        return context.Orders
                      .Include(o => o.Lines)
                      .ThenInclude(o => o.Product)
                      .Where(o => o.OrderId == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

This means you can't just pass the object from GetById to a component, let the user edit via the component, then reattach (ctx.Attach(order)) and save, as nothing will be flagged as modified.
Using ctx.Update(order), then saving, will resave everything within that entity, potentially there could be 100's of lines of items within the order that will get saved to the database needlessly.
Is there a known pattern for the best way to handle this?
I thought about attaching the returned entity to a fresh DbContext, but never querying or saving the to the database with that context. I hope it will not open a database connection, and therefore not need explicitly disposing.
Then I can query that DbContext's ChangeTracking to get the changes, them pass them changes to the correct update, add, remove short lived db contexts.
Or better yet, just using the change tracking abilities of EF Core, without a DbContext?

There are three ways Updating an entity

@AlexanderPetrov are you suggesting use query then update?

I think you might need to seperate this out more than you have.
If a user needs to load and look at an order, I would still have the GetById method to populate your frontend. When you're updating it I would then use an update method where you get the entity, update, and save it in that method. Something like this -
public Order UpdateById(int id, Order newOrder) // or whatever value you want to change
    {
        var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        Order trackedOrder = context.Orders.Include(o => o.Lines).ThenInclude(o => o.Product).Where(o => o.OrderId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        trackedOrder.value = newOrder.value;
        context.Orders.Update(trackedOrder)
    }

If you're on EF 7.0 or higher they have a new way of handling the actual updating but the concept is the same.
